# I need to change border side by arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, user-input

I want to change between the sides of borders by pressing the arrow keys

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        switch(e.which){
            case 38:$("#sh").css("border-top-color", "#fff"); //šipka nahoru
            break;
            case 40:$("#sh").css("border-bottom-color", "#fff"); //dolů
            break;
            case 37:$("#sh").css("border-left-color", "#fff"); //vlevo
            break;
            case 39:$("#sh").css("border-right-color", "#fff"); //vpravo
            break;
        }
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="score">Skóre: 0</div>
        <div id="player"><div id="sh"></div></div>
    <p class="enemy">o</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not know what you are actually trying to achieve, but this is my solution (note that your first need to click inside the window for it to work):

```js
$(function(){

left = 37,up = 38, right = 39,down = 40;

    $(window).keydown(function(e){
        switch(e.which){
            case 38: $("#sh").css('border', '2px solid #fff').css("border-top-color", "#000"); //šipka nahoru
            break;
            case 40: $("#sh").css('border', '2px solid #fff').css("border-bottom-color", "#000"); //dolů
            break;
            case 37: $("#sh").css('border', '2px solid #fff').css("border-left-color", "#000"); //vlevo
            break;
            case 39: $("#sh").css('border', '2px solid #fff').css("border-right-color", "#000"); //vpravo
            break;
        }
    }); 
});
```

```css
#sh {height: 100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="score">Skóre: 0</div>
        <div id="player"><div id="sh"></div></div>
    <p class="enemy">o</p>
```